# Problem creating multiple charts in the same page

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have two functions, each supposed to draw a different chart from the same dataset to two SVGs with id attributes of *one* and *two* respectively.

I have created different variables to append the chart to its corresponding SVG:

```
var svg1 = d3.select("#one")
var svg2 = d3.select("#two")
```

The problem is the function that draws chart for the second SVG overwrites both charts.

You can see the charts return correctly if you run each function separately. (Comment out each function call to see the data from the other chart that is being overwritten)

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrj803za/2/)

```
<html>
<body>
<svg id="one"></svg>
<svg id="two"></svg>
<script>
// variables we'll be filtering by
var quantile;
var amount;
var type;
var risk;

w = window.innerWidth;
h = window.innerHeight;

// <-- Make Selection -->
// Possible values --
// quantile: [1 2 3 4]
// variable: ['Income' 'Payments' 'Consumption' 'Utility']
// amount: [ 5000 30000 70000]
// type: ['Loan' 'ISA']
// risk: [1 2 3 4]

quantile = 1;
amount=5000;
type = 'Loan';
risk = 2;

getFirst();
getSecond();

function getFirst() {

variable= 'Income';

// chart stuff
 margin = {top: h/4, right: w/4, bottom: h/4, left: w/4},
    width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([0, width]);

y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([height,0]);

valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.key); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

var svg1 = d3.select("#one")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JainFamilyInstitute/isa-app/master/data/data_vis.csv?token=AXiiVXcAwXZjLK4-3tiyxKwj8yaVMVDmks5b6b8NwA%3D%3D", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // filter by selection
  data = data.filter(function(d) { 
          return (d.quantile == quantile) &
          (d.variable == variable) &
          (d.amount == amount) &
          (d.type == type) &
          (d.risk == risk) }); 

  // create visualizable array with only ages and amounts for selected series
  data_filtered = data.map(({ quantile,amount,risk,type,variable, ...item }) => item);
  data_vis = data_filtered[0];
  console.log(data_vis);

  result = [];
  for(i=22;i<101;i++){
    key = i;
    value =parseFloat(data_vis[i]);
    result.push({
            key: key,
            value: value
        });
  }

  // console.log(data_vis);
  console.log(result);

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain([d3.min(result, function(d) { return d.key; }), d3.max(result, function(d) { return d.key; })]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(result, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg1.append("path")
      .data([result])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);

  // Add the X Axis
  svg1.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add the Y Axis
    function y_grid_lines() {
    return d3.axisLeft(y)
  }

  svg1.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .call(y_grid_lines()
      .tickSize(-width)
      );

});

}


function getSecond() {

variable= 'Payments';

// chart stuff
margin = {top: h/4, right: w/4, bottom: h/4, left: w/4},
    width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([0, width]);

y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([height,0]);

valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.key); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

var svg2 = d3.select("#two")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JainFamilyInstitute/isa-app/master/data/data_vis.csv?token=AXiiVXcAwXZjLK4-3tiyxKwj8yaVMVDmks5b6b8NwA%3D%3D", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // filter by selection
  data = data.filter(function(d) { 
          return (d.quantile == quantile) &
          (d.variable == variable) &
          (d.amount == amount) &
          (d.type == type) &
          (d.risk == risk) }); 

  // create visualizable array with only ages and amounts for selected series
  data_filtered = data.map(({ quantile,amount,risk,type,variable, ...item }) => item);
  data_vis = data_filtered[0];
  console.log(data_vis);

  result = [];
  for(i=22;i<101;i++){
    key = i;
    value =parseFloat(data_vis[i]);
    result.push({
            key: key,
            value: value
        });
  }

  // console.log(data_vis);
  console.log(result);

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain([d3.min(result, function(d) { return d.key; }), d3.max(result, function(d) { return d.key; })]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(result, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg2.append("path")
      .data([result])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);

  // Add the X Axis
  svg2.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg2.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});

}
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible fix is to fetch your data once and the filter twice.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87jb0qz5/) I create using **d3v5** which uses *fetch API* making it easier to avoid this kind of issues. In general, be wary of callbacks when you write Javascript code.

The main change in this code is the following:

```
d3.csv("<remote csv>").then(function(data) {
getIncome(data);
getPayments(data);
});
```

The rest is quite similar to your code.

**EDIT**: Gerardo Furtado's answer also addresses an important issue regarding the cause of the issue. You should also follow the suggestions in that answer. My solution leaves the issue addressed in that answer unresolved. Instead, my answer focuses on ensuring the intended order of execution.

Comment: This was the issue. Forgot that the functions run asynchronous  - passing the data as parameters now works.

Answer (score 0):

A word of caution about Javascript: when you do this...

```
variable = 'Income';
```

... instead of:

```
var variable = 'Income';
```

... or even using `const` or `let`, your `variable` is a global variable, that is, it's not scoped inside `getIncome()` or `getPayments()`.

Together with the fact that the callback of `d3.csv` doesn't run immediately, this is what happens:

1. You call both functions, one after the other:

   ```
   getIncome();
   getPayments();
   ```
2. Inside `getIncome()`, you have:

   ```
   function getIncome() {
       variable= 'Income';
       //etc...
   ```

   which makes `variable` a global with `"Income"` as value.
3. Then, when it comes to `getPayments()`, you have:

   ```
   function getPayments() {
       variable= 'Payments';  
       //etc...
   ```

   now `variable` has `"Payments"` as value, but the callback from the first function (`getIncome()`) **was not executed yet**!

Therefore, when the first function runs, the value of `variable` is `"Payments"`, and both charts have the same path.

**Solution**: don't create globals, do not assign a value to an undeclared variable.

Here is your same Fiddle, just adding `var` in front of each variable: https://jsfiddle.net/qrj803za/3/

Also, take care of other globals you're creating here (like `result`, `data_vis`, etc...)